# Show estimate vs actual estimations in query plan

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-execution-plan

For some reason my plans dont show an actual vs estimation in the designer query plan. I have seen these show on Brent Ozar videos.  How do I get those to show?

[image]

Comment: What version of SSMS are you using?

Comment: v17.9.1 and SQL Server 2016

Comment: That's quite old. [Update to the latest version 18.9.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Oh gosh you're right.  It usually tells me when there is an update....

Comment: There are two separate buttons: actual and estimated. Make sure you clicked the right one

Comment: Also note that, even when viewing the *actual* execution plan, the cost % are still estimated value properties of the cached execution plan.

Comment: That worked, please put your answer and Ill mark it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep up to date with SSMS releases for the best new features!

V18 introduced more granular information in the graphical execution plans including cumulative elapsed times for operators (or individual elapsed time for batch mode operators), actual vs estimated row counts, percentage of estimated rows read and various other goodies.